# Does apple have a volume purchasing program (vpp) that includes Macs?

Tags: mac-appstore, volume-purchase-program

I have about 25 Mac users that I admin for and I can't seem to find a volume licensing/purchasing program for Macs.  Does one exist?

For example, Apple has removed iWork physical boxes from just about everywhere near my office and I can't get them from any of my vendors online.  The only way to get iWork now appears to be through the app store, but I don't want my users to be using their apple id's for the purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a volume purchase program for the Mac does exist!

http://www.apple.com/mac/volume-licensing/

Note that this looks like it is for Apple software only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a business-specific Apple Store located here: http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/browse/campaigns/business/introduction

Apple also maintains a fleet of direct-to-business sales personnel that you can talk to for volume purchases and after-purchase care for your staff. To contact them, call 1-800-854-3680.